# Can や mean "nor" in certain contexts?

Tags: meaning, particle-や

> Aがいくら強いといってもBやCとそれほど変わるもんじゃないはずだ。

Does や still imply other elements can be added here?

Answer (score 2):

It just means that the list is not exhaustive

Comment: What confuses me is that sometimes や used in contexts where it doesn't make sense for there to be more items added to the list. I've been told it's used that way to imply something else.

Answer (score 1):

や is a parallel particle.

> Aがいくら強いといってもBやCとそれほど変わるもんじゃないはずだ。

A, B and C have almost the same strength, all 3 are strong.

"Does や still imply other elements can be added here?"
→ Yes, kind of. When we say "BやC", we're not ruling out other elements for comparison. Because this type of comparison doesn't have to be so strict.

If we want to compare strictly A with B and C, it could be said for example "Aがいくら強いといってもBと比べて、またCと比べてそれほど変わるもんじゃないはずだ".